# Why does my requests decorator keep saying " too many calls " for my python webscraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am writing a code to extract the jersey numbers of all NFL players that have ever played professionally. What I cannot figure out is how to manage the requests efficiently without causing a "too many calls" exception.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tqdm
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
import time
import csv
import backoff
from ratelimit import limits, RateLimitException
from backoff import on_exception, expo
import os
import requests
import pickle

FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 900

@limits(calls=15, period=FIFTEEN_MINUTES)
def get_numbers(jersey):
    url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/uniform.cgi?number={jersey}'
    page = requests.get(url)
    #print(page.status_code)
    time.sleep(10)
    if page.status_code != 200:
        print('API response: {}'.format(page.status_code))
        print("waiting 30 seconds...")
        time.sleep(30)
        page = requests.get(url)
        if page.status_code != 200:
            print('API response: {}'.format(page.status_code))
            print("waiting 30 seconds...")
            time.sleep(30)
            page = requests.get(url)
        else:
            html_content = page.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
            return soup
    else:
        html_content = page.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
        return soup

data = {} # holds player data

def addplayerdata(data,uni_num):

    #add data to the dictionary
    # get table 
    soup = get_numbers(uni_num) # for jersey number 32
    #print(len(soup))
    player_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"id": "uniform_number"})
    
    table_body = soup.find("tbody")
    table_rows = table_body.find_all("tr") #--> nested  <tr then <th (...) <td
    for x in range(len(table_rows)):
        headings = []
        #time.sleep(5)
        for th in table_rows[x]:
            # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
            headings.append(th.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip())
        #print(headings)
        dict = {"Player Name":headings[0],"Year From":headings[1],"Year To":headings[1],"AV":headings[2]}
        data[uni_num] = dict
    return data

#unpickle the data here
try:
    with open('playerdata_dictfile.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        mydata = pickle.load(handle)
        print("loaded mydata...")
except Exception as e:
    mydata = {}
    print(e)

'''if len(str(mydata.read()))>0:
    dictionary = json.loads(str(mydata))
else:
    dictionary = {}'''
#mydata.close()
for uni in tqdm(range(0,618)):
    
    if uni not in mydata:
        #print(uni)
        try:
            mydata = addplayerdata(data,uni)
        except Exception as e:
            with open('playerdata_dictfile.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
                pickle.dump(mydata, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            print(e)  
            if str(e).find("too many calls")>-1: 
                for i in tqdm(range(0,100)):
                    time.sleep(.005)
                try:
                    mydata = addplayerdata(data,uni)
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
    else:
        print("already saved...")
        continue
print(data)
print("finished")
```

This results in output that is shown below (truncated because it is so long)

> {15: {'Player Name': 'Brandon Zylstra', 'Year From': '2018', 'Year To': '2018', 'AV': '2018'}, 16: {'Player Name': 'Jim Zyntell', 'Year From': '1935', 'Year To': '1935', 'AV': '1935'}, 17: {'Player Name': 'Joe Zeller', 'Year From': '1933', 'Year To': '1933', 'AV': '1938'}, 18: {'Player Name': 'Jim Zorn', 'Year From': '1985', 'Year To': '1985', 'AV': '1985'}, 19: {'Player Name': 'Isaiah Zuber', 'Year From': '2020', 'Year To': '2020', 'AV': '2021'}, 20: {'Player Name': 'Dick Zoll', 'Year From': '1938', 'Year To': '1938', 'AV': '1938'}, 21: {'Player Name': 'Jim Zyntell', 'Year From': '1933', 'Year To': '1933', 'AV': '1933'}, 22: {'Player Name': 'Roy Zimmerman', 'Year From': '1940', 'Year To': '1940', 'AV': '1942'}, 23: {'Player Name': 'Lou Zontini', 'Year From': '1944', 'Year To': '1944', 'AV': '1944'}, 24: {'Player Name': 'Dick Young', 'Year From': '1955', 'Year To': '1955', 'AV': '1955'}, 25: {'Player Name': 'Albert Zupek', 'Year From': '1946', 'Year To': '1946', 'AV': '1946'}, 26: {'Player Name': 'Dick Zoll', 'Year From': '1937', 'Year To': '1937', 'AV': '1937'}, 27: {'Player Name': 'Eric Zomalt', 'Year From': '1994', 'Year To': '1994', 'AV': '1996'}, 28: {'Player Name': 'Amos Zereoue', 'Year From': '2004', 'Year To': '2004', 'AV': '2004'}, 29: {'Player Name': 'Roy Zimmerman', 'Year From': '1948', 'Year To': '1948', 'AV': '1948'}, 30: {'Player Name': 'Charley Young', 'Year From': '1974', 'Year To': '1974', 'AV': '1976'}, 31: {'Player Name': 'Amos Zereoue', 'Year From': '2005', 'Year To': '2005', 'AV': '2005'}, 32: {'Player Name': 'Tony Zackery', 'Year From': '1989', 'Year To': '1989', 'AV': '1989'}, 33: {'Player Name': 'George Zorich', 'Year From': '1947', 'Year To': '1947', 'AV': '1947'}, 34: {'Player Name': 'Mickey Zofko', 'Year From': '1971', 'Year To': '1971', 'AV': '1974'}, 35: {'Player Name': 'George Zorich', 'Year From': '1946', 'Year To': '1946', 'AV': '1946'}, 36: {'Player Name': 'Mike Zordich', 'Year From': '1994', 'Year To': '1994', 'AV': '1998'}, 37: {'Player Name': 'George Youngblood', 'Year From': '1969', 'Year To': '1969', 'AV': '1969'}, 38: {'Player Name': 'Mike Zordich', 'Year From': '1987', 'Year To': '1987'...

My goal is to download every jersey number for the NFL (for a project) and use the pseudoscience of sports numerology to perform experiments over the 2021 season. I have subscribed to the website and have full access to the data but it requires inputting one number at a time which would take forever manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen such error occur with requests. I suspect you are getting it from third party ratelimit decorator.

You could also do something like this:

```py
import requests
import tenacity
from lxml import html
from requests import HTTPError
import pandas

session = requests.Session()


@tenacity.retry(retry=tenacity.retry_if_exception_type(HTTPError),
                wait=tenacity.wait_exponential(multiplier=1, min=2, max=30))
def get_jersey_page(number):
    url = f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/uniform.cgi?number={number}'
    response = session.get(url)
    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        raise

    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    return tree


def parse_player_data(number):
    tree = get_jersey_page(number)

    number_on_page = tree.xpath('//h1[contains(text(), "All Players To Wear")]')[0].text.split()[-1]
    if int(number_on_page) != number:
        print(f'Jersey number mismatch. On page {number_on_page}, expected {number}')
        return

    for row in tree.xpath('//th/a[contains(@href, "players/")]/ancestor::tr'):
        href = row.find('th/a')
        player_name = href.text
        player_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com' + href.attrib['href']
        year_min = row.findtext('td[@data-stat="year_min"]')
        year_max = row.findtext('td[@data-stat="year_max"]')

        player = {
            'jersey': number,
            'name': player_name,
            'url': player_url,
            'year_min': year_min,
            'year_max': year_max,
        }
        yield player


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = []
    for number in range(0, 100):
        for player in parse_player_data(number):
            data.append(player)

    df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel('player_data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Couple of notes:

Tenacity rety decorator is not strictly needed, it's there to show better approach for retrying.

There are is extra 3rd party dependency - pandas which will allow you to effortlessly export data to multiple data formats (like excel like I shown you in the snippet above). It will also allow you to do analysis and transformation should you need it sometime (highly recommended).

Also notice I used `requests.Session()`. This will somewhat speed up scraping as it will reuse connection, instead of spawning connection for each HTTP request. It's also more efficient for remote webserver, if it supports Connection Keep-Alive.

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try it.

Comment: added import openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

Is advanced rate limiting really necessary? This code allowed me to retrieve the data in less than two minutes:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

dfs = []

for i in tqdm(range(0,100)):
  df = pd.read_html(f'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/players/uniform.cgi?number={i}')[0]
  df['jersey'] = i
  dfs.append(df)
  time.sleep(1)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

|  | Player | From | To | AV | jersey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Reggie Begelton | 2019 | 2019 | nan | 0 |
| 1 | Ted Bucklin | 1931 | 1931 | nan | 0 |
| 2 | Darion Clark | 2019 | 2019 | nan | 0 |
| 3 | Lou Eaton | 1945 | 1945 | nan | 0 |
| 4 | Ox Eckhardt | 1928 | 1928 | nan | 0 |

42546 players in total

Comment: I was not able to get the same result from your code. Maybe there is something I am missing.